# Failed to insert image into MongoDB server using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I am trying to get the image when user submits the form and inserting it into mongoDB server.For image I am using Multer plugin but its showing me the error.Here is my code of NodeJS

```
const multer = require('multer');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mytable',{useNewUrlParser:true} )
.then(()=>
console.log("Mongodb connected"))
.catch(err => console.error("could not connected",err));
const Schema =new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    lastname:String,
    pass:String,
    phonenumber:String,
    zipcode:String,
    birthdate:String,
    img:  {contentType:String,data:Buffer }

});
Schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
var user = mongoose.model('mytable', Schema);
//Multer for include image into directory
app.use(multer({ dest: '/public/'}).single('files'));
app.post('/save',(req,res)=>{

    console.log("image is" +req.body.img);
    var model = new user();
       model.name = req.body.name,
        model.email=req.body.email,
        model.lastname=req.body.lastname,
        model.pass=req.body.pass,
        model.phonenumber=req.body.phonenumber,
        model.zipcode=req.body.zipcode,
        model.birthdate=req.body.birthdate,
     /*   model.img.data = req.body.img,  */
        model.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.userPhoto.path);
        newPic.image.contentType = 'image/png';
        model.save(function(err,doc){

    });
    res.json({result:'sucess'}); 
    res.end();
});
```

I just uploaded the required code. I am getting the error of **Cannot read property 'userPhoto' of undefined** .I don't know what should I write in fs.readFilesync.Please help me to insert image into a server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask Multer to handle a `.single()` file that is expected to be referred to by the input name `"files"`. According to the [doc](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#singlefieldname):

> The single file will be stored in `req.file`

But you try to access `req.files` instead. (And it seems you're expecting this file to be referred to as `"userPhoto"`, maybe?).

See also [what information](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) Multer exposes to retrieve the uploaded file's path.

Finally, you might want to restrict your [middleware usage](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to the routes that need it.

#### EDIT: a few comments

```
// This tells the WHOLE app that:
// when a request comes in, execute this
app.use(
  // Multer will do:
  // when I'm given an incoming request (here it's every request)
  // then I'm looking for *one* file being uploaded
  // this file should be named "files" (i.e. client has <input type="file" name="files">)
  // if I find it, then I store it in /public
  multer({ dest: '/public/'}).single('files')
);

// This tells the app that:
// if a request comes in for endpoint /save with method POST, this is the code to execute
app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
  // in here, Multer will have been executed already
});
```

So:

- does your form really names its file to be uploaded `"files"`? I'd guess your form names the file `"userPhoto"`... just a guess!
- if such a file exists in the request, Multer documentation says that your route handler can access it in `req.file` (not `req.files`)
- if not, Multer will just let the request pass (that's what middlewares do), so you won't have a `req.file`
- if `req.file` is mounted on the request by Multer, it exposes several data fields, such as `req.file.path`

I also hinted that you may not want to enable Multer for the whole app, but just for the routes that require it. Instead of a "global" `app.use`, you can define several times a route (or you could explicitly use the router, I don't see much of a difference), like:

```
app.post('/save', multer(...));
app.post('/save', (req, res) => {...});
// which can also be written as
app.post('/save', multer(...), (req, res) => {...});
```

This way, all other routes do not consider file uploading, I'm sure I don't need to highlight how better this is.

Comment: Hi,I am completely new about this.Can you please edit my code.I dont what to write in multer .I tried 5-6 different logics but it is not working. actually the image is coming from html form .

Comment: The documentation I linked would help you not stay "completely new about this". ;) I'll make an edit with some comments in your code to help you understand what happens, but I can't do it all since I lack some data to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with mongoose! as it says in your error message, `req.files` is undefined. it's a problem with `multer` documentation! when you're using single your file will be available in `req.file`
so this would fix your problem:

```
app.post('/save',(req,res)=>{

    console.log("image is" +req.body.img);
    var model = new user();
       model.name = req.body.name,
        model.email=req.body.email,
        model.lastname=req.body.lastname,
        model.pass=req.body.pass,
        model.phonenumber=req.body.phonenumber,
        model.zipcode=req.body.zipcode,
        model.birthdate=req.body.birthdate,
     /*   model.img.data = req.body.img,  */
        model.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path); // here's the fix
        newPic.image.contentType = 'image/png';
        model.save(function(err,doc){

    });
    res.json({result:'sucess'}); 
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.after implementing your result.I am getting this error:Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

```
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now } // stick that into the Schema
```